# Angular 2 attribute component is wrapping the template in the input tag

Tags: angular, components, angular2-ngcontent

I am attempting to create a DatePicker component in Angular 2.

I would like this to be an attribute component, so my html would look like:

```
<input type='text' datePicker [(ngModel)]='myDate' />
```

The problem is when rendering the template, it wraps it inside the input tag.

My template looks like this:

```
<ng-content></ng-content>
<div class="datePickerContainer">Test</div>
```

When I inspect the element in the browser, it looks like:

```
<input class='ng-pristine ng-valid' datepicker type="text" ng-reflect-date-picker>
    <div class="datePickerContainer">Test</div>
</input>
```

Which makes it invisible to the browser.  It really needs to be appended after the input tag.

What I am expecting to see is:

```
<input class='ng-pristine ng-valid' datepicker type="text" ng-reflect-date-picker />
<div class="datePickerContainer">Test</div>
```

How can I get my template to render after the input tag instead of having it wrapped inside of it?

Comment: `ng-pristine` will be have hidden property applied so on load the input element is not touched. so i will be hidden only

Comment: it's not possible, the compiler treats `input` as a component host element, and components content is rendered inside host element as per shadow root spec

Comment: Why not write a component datepicker which will contain <input ...> and <div class="calendar"></div> ?

Comment: @Vega I don't want to limit how the input interacts.  What if the user wants a placeholder?  What if they want to use it in a bootstrap inputgroup and add an icon?  There are just too many things that someone can do to an input and I don't want to handle each one inside the component.